# How should a delegate be returned for unmanaged code when called from a callback?

Tags: c#, c++, delegates, unmanaged, dllimport

I have a situation where I am stepping in and out of un/managed code, and I think my methodology is causing me to get a "FatalExecutionEngineError".  Specifically, I have a C# callback ("X") which returns another callback ("Y") into C#, where both X and Y are called by unmanaged C++ code (which is called by C#).  The error is thrown when returning from callback Y.

---

Dll Import Statements:

```
[DllImport ("SearchDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern unsafe bool Dll_Search_Text (..., delegate_add_result Fn);
```

---

The unmanaged C code:

```
extern "C" {
__declspec(dllexport) bool Dll_Search_Text (..., bool (*Add_Result (int, int)) (int, int, int)) {
    bool (*Add_Result_Word) (int, int, int);
    bool Add_Word_Ret;

    ...    
    Add_Result_Word = Add_Result ([int param], [int param]);
    if (0 == Add_Result_Word) return false;
    ...

        for (Itr=Set->begin (); Itr != Set->end (); Itr++) {
            ...
            Add_Word_Ret = Add_Result_Word ([int param], [int param], [int param]);   
            }
        }

    return true;
    }
}
```

---

Delegate definitions:

```
public delegate bool delegate_add_result_word (int A, int B, int C);
public delegate delegate_add_result_word delegate_add_result (int D, int E);
```

---

The error message:

```
"Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a
problem in 'C:\Neuric\bin\Search.exe'. Additional Information: The 
runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was
at 0x6ea2ceca, on thread 0x744. The error code is 0xc0000005. This 
error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable 
portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling
errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack."
```

---

The code works some of the time (and worked just fine before I added the nested callbacks), but throws this exception the rest of the time.

Comment: How are you converting .NET delegates into C function pointers, and what do you do to the function pointer/delegate to support the conversion?

Comment: What's the architecture x86 or x64?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegates generally use fastcall. But c style function pointers use cdecl. Tag your delegate with the UnamangedFuntionPointer-attribute.

Comment: A HA! I knew it was something like that, but I wasn't sure how to tag it as such.  THANK YOU! It works now. ^__^

Comment: @Amanduh, don't forget to vote for answers and mark the best one as answer.

Comment: @Eamon Nerbonne, Oh, thanks.  This is only my second time asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of *exactly* what you're doing, but there are two causes I can think of.  I'm assuming you've converted the delegate to a function pointer.  Then...

- You must ensure that the delegate object is not garbage collected.  The GC doesn't see your function pointer, so it'll clean up the delegate pronto.  There are a few handle handle-containers in namespace msclr, but if you're dealing with a complex scenario you may need to manually allocate `GCHandle`.  Of course, you may already be doing this ;-).
- You must further ensure that the reference to the GC-controlled object isn't moved while you access it.  `pin_ptr` is one way to do that locally, but you sound like your passing things around in a complicated fashion, so that may mean you need to manually pin an object, with [`GCHandle.Alloc(..., GCHandleType.Pinned)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1246yz8f.aspx)

Comment: I've been worried about such a scenario (but again, not sure exactly what the workaround would be), but using the information you gave me I was able to find this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/bd662199-d150-4fbf-a5ee-7a06af0493bb/  It seems that the delegate won't get moved around, but I do still have to figure out a way to "extend the delegates life".  I should be able to just add a reference to the delegate in my managed class, shouldn't I?

Comment: thanks for the link! indeed, a reference in your managed class should do fine, as long as the class itself is references somewhere, that is ;-).